# How do you rotate image in angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, rotation, angularjs-directive

Hi I have an image that I want to rotate.  There are two buttons left and right which rotate the image 45 degrees in opposite directions.  I tried creating a directive using jquery rotate library but it doesn't work.  Help?

directive.js

```
.directive('rotate', function() {
return {
    restrict:'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      console.log('hi');
        // watch the degrees attribute, and update the UI when it changes
        scope.$watch(attrs.degrees, function(rotateDegrees) {
            console.log(rotateDegrees);
            //transform the css to rotate based on the new rotateDegrees
  element.rotate(rotateDegrees);    

        });
    }
}
```

});

template.html

```
<p><img degrees='angle' rotate id='image' src='myimage.jpg'/> </p>
<a ng-click="rotate('-45')">Rotate Left</a>
<a ng-click="rotate('45')">Rotate Right</a>
```

controller.js

```
   $scope.rotate= function(angle) {

   $scope.angle=angle;
    };
```

Comment: There is another way. You can use ng-style:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22091733/dynamically-transform-in-css-using-ng-style

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do the rotation by setting the CSS in the directive

```
app.directive('rotate', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch(attrs.degrees, function (rotateDegrees) {
                console.log(rotateDegrees);
                var r = 'rotate(' + rotateDegrees + 'deg)';
                element.css({
                    '-moz-transform': r,
                    '-webkit-transform': r,
                    '-o-transform': r,
                    '-ms-transform': r
                });
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Hope it can shed some light on.

<kbd>**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CPKmN/)**</kbd>

Comment: Yes, but is there any way to get the image-url as rotated?

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to tell you my solution about rotating.

```
<img src="{{Image_URL}}" id="img{{$index}}" class="CssImage" />
<a href=""><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-repeat" id="rotateIcon" data-ng-init="rd=1;" data-ng-click="RotateImage('img'+ $index,rd);rd=rd+1;rd==4?rd=0:''"></span></a>
```

Here rd states for rotate degree time(x1,x2,x3,x4 -x4 =360 then resetting it to 0 )
Say that you have an ng-repeat  for images  in there created img ids.and in this span's ng-click I rotate the image by applying css .

```
$scope.RotateImage = function (id,deg) {
    var deg = 90 * deg;
    $('#' + id).css({
        '-webkit-transform': 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)',  //Safari 3.1+, Chrome  
        '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)',     //Firefox 3.5-15  
        '-ms-transform': 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)',      //IE9+  
        '-o-transform': 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)',       //Opera 10.5-12.00  
        'transform': 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)'          //Firefox 16+, Opera 12.50+  

    });
}
```

Just take as an Alternative , any comments  will be appreciated .

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.RotateImageRight = function () {
            z = z + 1;
            var img;
            if (z === 1) {
                img = document.getElementById("rotate90");
                img.style.transform = "rotate(-90deg)";
                img.style.width = "725px";

            }

            else if (z === 2) {
                img = document.getElementById("rotate90");
                img.style.transform = "rotate(-180deg)";
                img.style.width = "870px";
            }

            else if (z === 3) {
                img = document.getElementById("rotate90");
                img.style.transform = "rotate(-270deg)";
                img.style.width = "725px";
            }

            else if (z === 4) {
                img = document.getElementById("rotate90");
                img.style.transform = "rotate(-360deg)";
                img.style.width = "870px";
            } else {
                z = 0;
            }

        }
```

Comment: simply invoke the function on your button(ng-click=" RotateImageRight ()")