# Dynamically transform in css using ng-style

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I could not get `transform` to work when it's inside `ng-style`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.x" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.13/angular.js" data-semver="1.2.13"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div style="transform: rotate(3deg);-webkit-transform: rotate(3deg);-ms-transform: rotate(3deg)">Test</div>
    <div ng-style="{"transform": "rotate({{number}}deg)", "-webkit-transform": "rotate({{number}}deg)", "-ms-transform": "rotate({{number}}deg)"}">{{number}}</div>
    <input type="number" ng-model="number" value=1>
  </body>

</html>
```

Link: http://plnkr.co/edit/txSzAKxLDq48LVitntro?p=preview

If I change the `input` number the top div should change and **spin** at the same time. It should look like the word **Test** above it when it has value of 3.

So how to get `transform` to work in this case?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to escape those quotes inside the HTML attribute

Comment: Is this ok: http://plnkr.co/edit/93zsv34W8ccrL0cArUXl?p=preview ?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can't use brace binding inside a JS string inside an attribute. You can append the variable onto the string instead:

```
<div ng-style="{'transform': 'rotate('+number+'deg)', '-webkit-transform': 'rotate('+number+'deg)', '-ms-transform': 'rotate('+number+'deg)'}">{{number}}</div>
```

Also, I replaced your double-quotes with singles.

However, you might consider adding a function to your controller to return the appropriate style:

**Controller:**

```
// Create a variable to store the transform value
$scope.transform = "rotate(0deg)";
// When the number changes, update the transform string
$scope.$watch("number", function(val) {
    $scope.transform = "rotate("+val+"deg)";
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<!-- We can now use the same value for all vendor prefixes -->
<div ng-style="{'transform': transform, '-webkit-transform': transform, '-ms-transform': transform }">{{number}}</div>
```

[Updated Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/mpuxlr5z0pn6CJ2rCU7Y?p=preview)

Comment: Awsome! Thanks. It was just the thing I was looking for :)

Comment: You can add all your css rules inside a json object on your `scope`, it will be more readable. See this plunker from the doc: http://plnkr.co/edit/y8CeZq?p=preview

Comment: @bertrandg You can't actually do that with CSS vendor prefixes in Angular though. They get normalized to drop off the `-webkit-` and `-ms-` prefixes. [See this example](http://plnkr.co/edit/AFx2WSc6NXceFMcAk9ye?p=preview)

Comment: exact, interesting I didn't know this behavior.

Comment: I'd make a function returning an object with the style rules, to keep the html cleaner.