# How to apply transform translate property to element using ngStyle in Angular2+

Tags: javascript, css, angular

I'm trying to conditionally apply a `transform: translateX($value)` directly to the template element using `[ngStyle]` but I cannot find anyone talking about this. Mainly because I don't know what to search for :D.

I've seen some approaches doing basic styling with `[style.color]` or something a bit more advanced with `[attr.style]="{'transform': 'translateX(4rem)'}"` but the last one returns in the rendered HTML this: `style="unsafe"`. I've seen that you can use the `Sanitizer` to sanitize or bypass your styles/scripts etc... but at this point it was starting to 'smell' like something that you're not supposed to do? I'm looking for a clean way to achieve this. But I have no clue on where to look.

Thanks in advance to everyone!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22091733/dynamically-transform-in-css-using-ng-style

Comment: `[ngStyle]="{'transform': 'translateX(' + $value + ')'}"`

Comment: @Arg0n thanks! If you want to create the answer I'll mark it as solved :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use `[ngStyle]` as follows, assuming you have a `$value` variable in your controller:

```
[ngStyle]="{'transform': 'translateX(' + $value + 'px)'}"
```

and suppose you want to change both the axis having controller variables $x , $y

```
[ngStyle]="{'transform': 'translate(' + $x + 'px, ' + $y + 'px)'}"
```

Answer (score 21):

Alternatively you can use

```
[style.transform]="'translateX('+ $value + 'px)'"
```

It is essentially the same thing but I prefer this syntax.

Comment: hi jon i am confused what is the use of + (plus) symbols before and after the varable

Comment: Hi, it's because the value is a string i.e. `"string here " + myVariable + " joining another string"`

Answer (score -1):

**[style.transform]="'translateX('+value+'px)'"** worked for me in Angular.

**$value** gave me an error.