# AngularJS rotate an arrow based on $scope.bearing

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to rotate an arrow image based on a scope variable `$scope.bearing`. I have seen a few examples using CSS classes, but without setting up 360 of them, and having to manage the removal of the existing one and add a new one... sounds impractical. I did find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18840446/1671473) that does it programmatically on a button click, but I'm still kind of at a loss as to how I can set it from my scope variable without getting into some jQuery in the controller when the value is updated, and if I'm doing that, I may as well just use JQuery and CSS.

For example:

```
locSvc.addUpdateListener(function(pos, dir, spd) {
    console.log("handleLocationChange()");
    $scope.location = pos;
    $scope.bearing = dir;
    $scope.speed = spd;

    $('#bearing-indicator').css({
        "-webkit-transform": "rotate(" + dir+"deg)",
        "-moz-transform": "rotate(" + dir+"deg)",
        "transform": "rotate(" + dir+"deg)"
    });
});
```

Comment: please make a plunker

Comment: I don't have anything that works, or does not work. I'm not sure how to this together, hence the question :)

Comment: You must have some event to rotate it. But I didn't find anywhere in your code